# Defining column in SQL Server 2008 so that it substituts NULL with... let's say -1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm curious if it would be possible to define a table so it substitutes any NULL values with let's say -1?

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
   MyColumn1 int NOT NULL
   MyColumn2 int NOT NULL,
   MyColumn3 int NULL CASE WHEN ISNULL THEN -1 END
)
GO
```

Comment: Why allow NULL values if you want to convert them to -1?

Comment: I'm importing data from csv file that might or might not have nulls, If I don't allow NULL values importing data process fails (i'm using bulk upload), but if I have null values it mess up my join clauses in later stages, I thought that having null substituted with -1 would work nice....

Comment: If you were importing using SSIS you could transform it to -1 on the way in. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    MyColumn1 int NOT NULL,
    MyColumn2 int NOT NULL,
    MyColumn3 int NULL DEFAULT(-1)
)
```

you'd need to create a trigger as well to enforce that any NULLs got changed to -1.

Comment: I accept your answer since I was investigating using computed column before and didn't like it. I like your note about the trigger since without triggers I can not ensure non null values, but I didn't like the trigger too. I end up using view (with case statement) whenever I needed data. WOULDN'T IT BE NICE IF YOU CAN DEFINE FIELD WITH SUBSTITUTE STATEMENT THAT WOULD SUBSTITUTE NULL WITH WHATEVER YOU PROVIDE?

Comment: @krul - Using a `View` with a `CASE` statement doesn't have any particular benefit over using a non persisted computed column with a `CASE` statement that I can see? But in your case I would just fix the data after import or with a trigger anyway if you are using this calculated field in joins.

Answer (score 4):

This would be an extra [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx), or define as NOT NULL with a default of -1

Comment: a computed column would prevent you form setting it to something you actually want, unless you want it to mimic another column(s) from your row.

Comment: @racerx: a computed column generally uses another column. It avoids using code or triggers too which is why I suggested it. Triggers can be disabled and will cause a double write.

Comment: yea, but for the OP's table you need the original 3 columns: (column1, column2, column3) and the extra computed column. It would be something like column3a, which would be a ISNULL(column3,-1). This would get around the trigger, but you would need to write the code to write column3 but read column3a, or some other "work around", which would be worse than a trigger IMO

Comment: You define column3a based on col3 in the *table* definition... what code do you need exactly...? Select a different column to inserting? Hardly